# Audi A4 Spark Plug Broke Off Into Engine

Tags: audi

I have an Audi A4 B8 1.8T and managed to break a spark plug so the bottom half was stuck in a cylinder. When trying to remove it however, I used an easy out that was too small for the spark plug threads and now the spark plug tip has broken off into the cylinder along with the easy out itself. I can not afford a mechanic so I'm going to try fix it all myself. How deep do I have to go to fix all this now?

Comment: You need to invest in an endoscope and one of these https://www.amazon.com/SV-NN-Nozzle-Needle-Vacuum-Cleaner/dp/B00LOWP37I for the vacuum or some extra length needle nose pliers, otherwise you'll have to start taking off the head to reach the cylinder, or you could even use this https://www.liveactionsafety.com/ambu-res-que-manual-suction-pump/?gclid=EAIaIQobChMI6Kabmpzw5AIVEvDACh1WigaREAQYASABEgLztPD_BwE with an extra clear hose attached to the end

Comment: Here's a humorous and detailed video saga of someone with a similar problem. Near the end he describes removing particulates from the cylinder.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JijVI3RTkMY

Comment: At the fastest scale, a good eye with a flashlight and one of those cheap mechanic grabber tools that bend, where the 4 prongs come out when you push the handle, not sure what they're called

Comment: Add a thin magnet on a stick to the above.

Comment: @GdD a staple of my toolbox - not that I drop things down plug holes, but also holds screws in difficult places etc...

Comment: Absolutely agree it's an essential @SolarMike

Comment: @hello-moto   Pearl grabber.